# Possible to bind HTML5 audio currentTime to input range value in Angular2?

Tags: angular, html5-audio

I'm trying to make a scrub bar for an audio player. I have a HTML 5 audio player created with `var audioPlayer = new Audio()`. I'd like to bind a HTML `<input type="range">` so that 1) the range reflects the audio position but also when I click the range, it changes the audio position to the new position. I am doing like this:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="{{ audioPlayer.duration }}" [value]="audioPlayer.currentTime" (input)="audioPlayer.currentTime = $event.target.value">
```

I am able to change the `currentTime` by clicking the range slider, but the range slider doesn't move when `currentTime` changes so it doesn't reflect the current audio position.

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't the value bind properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngModel` for [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---):

```
<input 
  type="range" 
  min="0"
  max="{{max}}"
  [(ngModel)]="currentTime"/>
```

Here is a working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-way-range-input

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed have the ngModel-thing missing and I was trying to bind to value. However, even though it works with the number in your example, for some reason one-way nor two-bindings happen when I try to bind to the audio player property currentTime.

Comment: Are you certain you are using `[(ngModel)]` and not `[(value)]`? Try using the example I provided in your code. I updated it to use an object called `audioPlayer` with a `currentTime` property.

Comment: Yea… I double checked. But my audioPlayer is of type Audio() and currentTime is a property that updates when the sound plays. Can there be some conflict there that you can't bind to that property as it is? I'll try to test some more...

Comment: Yes that was it. I solved this by adding an "ontimeupdate" callback to the audio object:

audioPlayer.ontimeupdate = () => { this.playposition = this.audioPlayer.currentTime }

Then I bound the playposition variable with ngModel by using your solution. The (input) has to manipulate playposition as well instead of the audioPlayer.currentTime. There's something in it that prevents it from being bound.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer to let others know that it was useful and that it answered your question. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Ahhh… currentTime isn't a variable but it's a getter/setter so binding doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the missing ngModel-binding, I had another problem there as well. Property `currentTime` of Audio-object seems to be a getter/setter so a direct binding doesn't seem to work.

I solved this by binding the range input to a local number variable `playbackPosition` instead and then added an `ontimeupdate`-callback to the audio player object that copies the `currentTime` value to the `playbackPosition` variable:

```
  this.audioPlayer = new Audio();
  this.audioPlayer.ontimeupdate = () => {
    this.playbackPosition = this.audioPlayer.currentTime;
    console.log("timeupdate")
  }
```